# Laravel 5.2 - Fazer relacionamento Many To Many entre registros de uma mesma tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento, laravel-5.2

As tabelas:

- A tabela `users`, registra usuários que podem ter N funções que são armazenadas na tabela `funcoes` (aluno, responsavel, professor, etc).
- A tabela `funcao_user` é pivot que faz o relacionamento Many To Many entre `users` e `funcoes`.

Até aqui, tudo ok.

Um usuário que possui uma função de aluno pode ter N usuários com a função de responsavel e, um usuário que possui a função de responsavel por ter N usuários com a função de aluno, ou seja, existe um relacionamento Many To Many dentro da tabela users.

Para esse relacionamento, criei a tabela pivot `aluno_responsavel` com os campos:
`aluno_id`, `responsavel_id` e `parentesco` (em relação ao responsável, indica pai, mãe, etc):

```
 Schema::create('aluno_responsavel', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->integer('aluno_id')->unsigned();            
     $table->integer('responsavel_id')->unsigned();
     $table->string('parentesco');
     $table->foreign('aluno_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
     $table->foreign('responsavel_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Como seria o relacionamento entre as tabelas `users` e `aluno_responsavel` no model User?

Comment: Só fazer o referencesMany em ambos os lados para o Model de User

Comment: poxa ... é complicado pelo visto, `aluno_id` e `responsavel_id` são apontadas para mesma tabela e o mesmo campo, para mim te uma normalização errada ai ...

Comment: Obrigado pela participação, @VirgilioNovic e @gmsantos! Encontrei uma discussão sobre o mesmo caso com informações que se aproximam bastante do que procuro, mas ainda não pude testar essas informações. Quando eu testar eu informo o resultado. ---> https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/441

Answer (score 0):

Com as informações encontradas em https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/441 fiz o seguinte relacionamento no model e funcionou (para simplificar os testes, deixei a coluna parentesco de fora):

```
public function responsaveis()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'aluno_responsavel', 'aluno_id', 'responsavel_id');
}
```

Com isso, eu consigo armazenar os ids `aluno_id` e `responsavel_id` com o seguinte comando no controller:

```
$user->responsaveis()->attach($request->responsavel_id);
```

Mas, ainda preciso saber como recuperar os valores armazenados na tabela pivot.
Fiz esta tentativa, mas não traz os dados esperados:

```
$userAluno = User::find($user_id);

foreach ($userAluno->responsaveis as $responsavel) {
     echo $responsavel->responsavel_id . <br />;
}
```

Comment: Voce criou um model para Responsável e outro para Users? Como estão seus models?

Comment: Olá @Evert! Não fiz um model para Responsavel pois não existe a tabela responsavel, apenas a tabela pivot aluno_responsavel. O model User está assim: public function funcoes() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Funcao'); } public function responsaveis() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'aluno_responsavel', 'aluno_id', 'responsavel_id'); }